# Using Material UI, how to get two images to stack vertically to the right of another larger image?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

Suppose I have three images. One is twice the height of the other two and I would like to design a simple grid where the two smaller ones stack vertically to the right of the larger one. The aspect ratios of the photos means they will work in a five-column layout if the larger one takes up 2 rows x 3 columns and the smaller ones take up 1 row x 2 columns. I'm using the Material UI GridList component (https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list/) and following the API documentation. No matter what settings I use, one of the smaller images renders to the right of the larger one, then there is a equal-sized tile of blank space below it, and the third image stacks vertically underneath the larger one to the left.

I suspect this is not React-specific, but some simple HTML or CSS problem I'm not familiar with. I guess I was expecting the component to do this automatically. In the demo (https://material-ui.com/demos/grid-list/) it automatically fills in horizontal space with images, but now that I'm looking, it does not appear do the same for vertical space.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import GridListTileBar from '@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar';

export class ImageGrid extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const tileData = [
    {
      img: "ex_1.jpg",
      title: 'Image',
      author: 'author',
      cols: 3,
      rows:2,
    },
    {
      img: "ex_3.jpg",
      title: 'Image',
      author: 'author',
      cols: 2,
      rows:1,
    },
    {
      img: "ex_2.jpg",
      title: 'Image',
      author: 'author',
      cols: 2,
      rows:1,
    },

  ];
  const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
    gridList: {
      width: 1384,
      height: 320,
      float:right,
    },
  });


     return (

     <div className={styles.root}>
      <GridList component='div' cellHeight={150} spacing={8} cols={5} className={styles.gridList}>
        {tileData.map(tile => (
          <GridListTile component='div' cols={tile.cols} rows={tile.rows} key={tile.img}>
            <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
            <GridListTileBar
              title={tile.title}
              subtitle={tile.author}
            />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>

  );
  }
}
```